# Line and Perpendicular segment from a Isolated Point, Get all Coordinates

Tags: c#, math, geometry, 2d, computational-geometry

I need to resolve this by using the least amount of calculation possible using C#.

I have the points (x0, y0); (y1, y1); (x2, y2):
  **(x1, y1); (x2, y2)** define a line, but is an segment **"S"**.
  and **(x0, y0)** is an isolated point, and the distance **"d"** shorter segment is a segment perpendicular, which has a distance **"d"**.

I have calculated **"d"** using this formula http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Point-LineDistance2-Dimensional.html and also calculated the value of **"r"** using **"Distance between two points"**.

```
    public static Double GetDistance(Point sourcePoint, Point destinyPoint)
    {
        Double horizontalDistance = (destinyPoint.X - sourcePoint.X);
        Double verticalDistance = (destinyPoint.Y - sourcePoint.Y);
        Double distance = System.Math.Sqrt((horizontalDistance * horizontalDistance) + (verticalDistance * verticalDistance));
        return distance;
    }
```

Actually I need to find the coordinates of the red dot.

[image]

Comment: Use dot product between the `x1,y1->x2,y2` and `x1,y1->x0,y0` vectors to get angle at  `redDot`,`1`,`0` (let's call it `angle1`, lower left dot). Angle between `0`,`redDot`,`1` is 90 (red dot), therefore angle of `1`,`0`,`redDot` (right point) is `90-angle1`. You have length of `d`, now you have angle too, so you have a vector of known length and position, so `redDot` coordinates can be found using [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638437/given-an-angle-and-length-how-do-i-calculate-the-coordinates). Where `0` is `(x0, y0)`, `1` is `(x1, y1)`, etc..

Comment: Can you post some pseudocode? to understand a little more.

Comment: Eh.. my math is super rusty, which has got me feeling down. But here's a super crappy picture to look at: [picture](http://i.imgur.com/3id7r6T.png). Note you'll have to shift the `C` vector from the origin to (x0, y0), then find its endpoint (or do vice-versa, doesn't matter). Also I got the polar coordinates backwards, it goes (length, angle), and I put (angle, length).

Comment: If you can use vectors (or implement your own Vector), you can solve it easily with [orthogonal projection](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Linear_Algebra/Orthogonal_Projection_Onto_a_Line)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you can find `s` easily with

```
double s = Math.Sqrt(r*r - d*d);
```

Then find the distance between point1 and point2

```
double distance = GetDistance(point1, point2);
```

Now you can solve for the position of the red dot.

```
double redX = (x2-x1) / distance * s;
double redY = (y2-y1) / distance * s;
```

---

**Easy method**

If you can use vectors (like Vector2 in [System.Numerics.Vectors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.vector2%28v=vs.111%29.aspx)), it will be a very simple [orthogonal projection](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Linear_Algebra/Orthogonal_Projection_Onto_a_Line) problem.

```
Vector2 p1 = new Vector2(point1.X, point1.Y);
Vector2 p2 = new Vector2(point2.X, point2.Y);
Vector2 p0 = new Vector2(point0.X, point0.Y);

Vector2 s = p2 - p1;
Vector2 v = p0 - p1;

double len = Vector2.Dot(v, s) / Vector2.Dot(s, s);
Vector2 projection = len * s;

// Finally get the position of your red dot
Point pointRedDot = point1 + new Point(projection.X, projection.Y);

Console.WriteLine(pointRedDot);
```

Comment: did you mean `p1 + len * s`

Comment: Yes I fixed my typo. Also converted back to a `Point`

Comment: Following the first step not get the correct coordinates of Redpoint.

Comment: `double s = Math.Sqrt(r*r + d*d);` is supposed to be `double s = Math.Sqrt(r*r - d*d);` (replace `+` with `-`)

Comment: @Cheva Yes it's supposed to be s = r^2 - d^2

Comment: Ok, but r = GetDistance(x1y1, x0y0) and d = Distance from x0y0 to line S (x1y1) ( x2y2).?

Comment: Using first step with **"+"** to **"-"** fix I have the example result, [link](http://imgur.com/f0TR8Do)

Comment: @LibertyLocked Can u explain a little more please? are you assuming that "r" and "d" are distances cartesian distances.? or vectors? I have "r" and "d" as float distances. "r" between points and "d" from point to line "S".